# Функции в python3 помогите!

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет. Пожалуйста, объясните разницу между 1) и 2)
Мне не понятен момент только с return.
Почему вариант 1) работает, а вариант 2) - нет

1)

```
def summ(x, y):
    if x > 5:
        x += 5
    return x + y
```

2)

```
def summ(x, y):
    if x > 5:
        x += 5
        return x + y
```

Comment: Оба варианта работают. Поясни, что именно тебе кажется не работающим?

Comment: Вариант 2) возвращает None, а вариант 1) - нормальный, правильный результат.

Comment: Сделай х больше 5, будет и во втором варианте "нормальный правильный результат". В вопросе, кстати, написано наоборот - что 2 работает, а 1 нет.

Comment: Извиняюсь, моя вина перепутал, + не увидел эту глупую ошибку)

Comment: вариант 2 возвращает значение только если `x > 5`, иначе ничего не возвращается, что эквивалентно возврату `None`

Comment: Просто писал проект на Django, не там return у функции-контроллера поставил, потом искал ошибку 5 часов. Всем спасибо, вопрос решён!

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае мы возвращаем x + y в любом случае, а во втором только если x > 5, а если это не так функция ничего не возвратит.

Например:

```
x = 4
y = 3
```

x не больше 5, поэтому просто выведет 7(первый случай) или ничего(второй случай);

```
x = 6
y = 3
```

x больше 5, поэтому выведет 6 + 5 + 3 = 14